How to put objects with its parents to a random collection in blender via python?
I want to put multiple objects with its parents to a random collection in my blender file and every object with its parents should move to only one collection. So all collections should have only one object with its linked parents objects inside. How can I do that?

Hello. So you have n objects in your scene and n collections, you want each collection to have exactly one object linked to it randomly ?

yes that is correct

do the collections already exist? so your .blend file already has exactly the same amount of empty collections as it does objects? and all you want to do is put 1 object into 1 collection and repeat until all objects are in a collection??

Yes I have the exact same amount of empty collections but I want each object with linked parents to move to a random collection. So one collection gets one object with all its parents.

What have you tried as far?

import bpy
import random

C = bpy.context

objects = C.selected_objects
collections = C.view_layer.layer_collection.children
random.shuffle(objects)

def remove_from_all_collections(object):
    for col in object.users_collection:
        col.objects.unlink(object)

for collection, object in zip(collections,objects):
    remove_from_all_collections(object)
    collection.collection.objects.link(object)
    if object.parent is not None:
        remove_from_all_collections(object.parent)
        collection.collection.objects.link(object.parent)

